# Images not loading after Deployed, working in development

Tags: laravel, vue.js, deployment

I'm trying to get images in my vue laravel app, from my DB.

When I run this in development, no problems it works, it also builds. It is deployed to a Forge server, but for some reason it fails to get anything when deployed.
in the get request `this.configurations = response.data;` gives an empty `[]`?

What could posible be different from dev to production in this context?

##### Route

```php
Route::get('/planner/show', [PlannerController::class, 'show'])
    ->name('planner.show');
```

##### Controller

```
//planner.show route
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $size = $request->input('size');
    $type = $request->input('type');

    if ($size == "all") {
        $rows = FrontpageConfiguration::where('type', $type)
            ->get();
    } else {
        $rows = FrontpageConfiguration::where('size', $size)
            ->where('type', $type)
            ->get();
    }

    return response()->json([
        'rows' => $rows
    ]);
}
```

##### View

```html
<template>
    <div v-for="item in configurations.rows" :key="item.id">
        <a :href="route('editor.unique', { uniqueValue: removeFileExtension(item.identifier) })">
            <img :src="getAllImgPath(item.url)" class="img-fluid" alt="Image">
        </a>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            configurations: [],
            type: "dusk",
            size: '2seater',
            rows: [],
        };
    },

    mounted(){
        this.getRows("all")
    },

    methods: {

        removeFileExtension(name){
            let lastIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.');
            name = name.substring(0, lastIndex);
            console.log(name);
            return name
        },

        getAllImgPath(url,) {
            var startIndex = url.indexOf("/assets/"); // Find the index of "/assets/"
            var modifiedUrl = url.substring(startIndex);
            const path = `${modifiedUrl}`;
            return path;
        },

        getRows(size) {
            axios
                .get(route('planner.show'), {
                    params: {
                        size,
                        type: this.type
                    },
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.configurations = response.data;
                    console.log(this.configurations);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        },

    },

};
</script>
```

When dd($rows} is done before the return statement i get this: "we" is the name of one of the files, but it dont have the filextension .jpg it is supposed to? The plot thickens

error 500:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1223 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/PlannerController.php:31
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

```
we{message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"
config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message: "Request failed with status code 500"
name: "AxiosError"
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response: {data: '\x3Cscript> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc)…re>\x3Cscript>Sfdump("sf-dump-1017236826")\x3C/script>\n', status: 500, statusText: 'Internal Server Error', headers: Vo, config: {…}, …}
stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500\n    at Rg (http://143.42.22.24/build/assets/app-5cf3188f.js:3:952)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.m (http://143.42.22.24/build/assets/app-5cf3188f.js:3:4051)"
[[Prototype]]: Error
```

Comment: I mean, if you don't show `route('planner.show')` controller, how are we supposed to know what could the issue be? If it changes just based on environment (same database and data on it), then it could be a configuration issue (`config` folder or `.env` data), so please, do share the controller/method of that route... Javascript has nothing to do here

Comment: Thanks alot, i was fixed on the javascript but you are offcause right, here is the route

Comment: Well, based on the code, it could be that `$rows` is literally an empty `Collection` due to the filter not matching anything, so `->get()` returns nothing = `[]`, but you are not doing `this.configurations = response.data.rows`, so I am not sure why you get `[]` instead of `{ rows: [] }`, could you make sure that `response.data` returns `[]` instead of what I mentioned? Check the query and make sure you are getting something back by adding a `dd($rows)` before the `return` in the controller (yes, it will not return json, it is for debugging purposes)?

Comment: I am sorry for being unclear, i does indeed the the proxy object  { rows: []}  and the problem is that it works fine when i do npm run dev it gives me the rows : [ with the data], but when deployed nothing. I will do the dd() now and check

Comment: When deployed, does it still return `{ rows: [] }` or just `[]`? I am thinking you have no data on the database, or you have a misconfiguration on the database like maybe a different database selected but you do have the tables just with no data

Comment: when deployed { rows : [] }, when not deployed locally {rows: [ full of data i need from db]}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253810/discussion-between-soma-juice-and-matiaslauriti).

Comment: You have a `500` error, check the logs and share what error it is comming back